# Stop function random number

Tags: function

i want stop this function with a button, what can i do for that working ?

Thanks

```
var module = angular.module('numberApp', []);

module.controller('NumberController', function($scope, $timeout) {
    (function update() {
    $timeout(update, 1000 * 15);
    $scope.randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*($scope.max-$scope.min+1)+$scope.min);
  }());
```

please help me to stop this function with a button ;-)

Comment: Halting a function has nothing to do with randomness. Removed the `random` tag. You should add a tag for the language you’re using though.

Answer (score 0):

```
var module = angular.module('numberApp', []);

module.controller('NumberController', function($scope, $timeout) {
    (function update() {
    $timeout(update, 1000 * 15);
    $scope.randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*($scope.max-$scope.min+1)+$scope.min);
  }());
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**